# PDO is not writing to MySQL, where did I go wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, var

I just have rewritten my mysql code to PDO, but I just don't get it working. I've been debugging, but just don't seem te be getting it right. It is all new for me, but it connect tot the database, it reads from the database in my vardump, but it won't post in the textarea, or even echo for that matter. Let alone, writing to the database... I've got a gut feeling that is it the $result var that is doing some weird stuff, but I doublechecked everything as far as I know.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Milan CMS</title>
    </head>

<body>

    <?php
        $host= "";
        $dbname= "";
        $username= "";
        $password= "";
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM milan WHERE tag='trainingen'");
        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();
        var_dump($result);
        echo $result['value'];
        echo $result;   
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" name="trainingen">
    Trainingen:<textarea name="nametrainingen" rows="10" cols="60"><?php echo $result['value']; ?></textarea></p>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Verzenden"><input type="reset" value="Veld leeg maken">
    </form>

    <?php
        $invoer = $_POST['nametrainingen'];

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //test if submit button is clicked
        $sql = "DELETE FROM milan WHERE tag = 'trainingen'";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO milan (tag, value) VALUES ('trainingen', '$result')";   
        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();
        $myFile = "trainingen.json"; 
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh, json_encode($result));
        fclose($fh);}
    ?>
<p>
</body>
</html>
```

Output of the var_dump:

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(6) { 
        ["id"]=> string(1) "0" 
        [0]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["tag"]=> string(10) "trainingen" 
        [1]=> string(10) "trainingen" 
        ["value"]=> string(17) "Hgioejigojerigjer" 
        [2]=> string(17) "Hgioejigojerigjer" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could you also include the output of your `var_dump($result)`?

Comment: @andrewsi array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(1) "0" [0]=> string(1) "0" ["tag"]=> string(10) "trainingen" [1]=> string(10) "trainingen" ["value"]=> string(17) "Hgioejigojerigjer" [2]=> string(17) "Hgioejigojerigjer" } } Array

Comment: @mtjiran You have to loop through result or if you are sure that it will always return one item access to value `$result[0]['key']` (`key` is `'value'` in your example.

Comment: @PLB In the HTML I've done this, but without the [0], wat is that? *I'm sure it only has one item to acces...

Comment: @mtjiran Take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now... So that's that for the output, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //test if submit button is clicked
    $sql = "DELETE FROM milan WHERE tag = 'trainingen'";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO milan (tag, value) VALUES ('trainingen', '$result')";   
    $sth->execute();
```

That's just going to re-run the previous contents of `$sth` - you'll need to prepare those two statements and then run them. You need to run them like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //test if submit button is clicked
    $sql = "DELETE FROM milan WHERE tag = 'trainingen'";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO milan (tag, value) VALUES ('trainingen', '$result')";   
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
```

Editted to add:

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
var_dump($result);
echo $result['value'];
echo $result;
```

`$result` ends up with an array of values - you'll have to step through each item in the array.

Comment: $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM milan WHERE tag='trainingen'"); This is not a problem to be ran again, because it will still get the value of 'trainingen' isn't it? Even after the intended update?

Comment: It's not a problem if it runs again, but your DELETE and INSERT statements will never be run.

Comment: I believe you, but don't understand you, how is $sth->execute(); preventing the delete and insert statements from running?

Comment: When you create your $sth variable, you give it an SQL statement to run (`$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * ...`). For your DELETE and INSERT statements, you're just defining them, but never actually using them - `$sql` isn't used anywhere else.

Comment: Excuse me for being ignorant, but how do I execute my DELETE and INSERT statements? Because I tried $SQL->execute(); but that returns: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute()

Comment: thanks for the solution. I think I just need to play around with this, because I now understand the concept of prepared statements and how they interact.